# C# GroupJoin efficiency

Tags: c#, .net, join, compare

without using GroupJoin:

```
var playersDictionary = players.ToDictionary(player => player.Id,
    element => new PlayerDto { Rounds = new List<RoundDto>() });

foreach (var round in rounds)
{
    PlayerDto playerDto;
    playersDictionary.TryGetValue(round.PlayerId, out playerDto);

    if (playerDto != null)
    {
        playerDto.Rounds.Add(new RoundDto { });
    }
}

var playerDtoItems = playersDictionary.Values;
```

using GroupJoin:

```
var playerDtoItems =
    from player in players
    join round in rounds
    on player.Id equals round.PlayerId
    into playerRounds
    select new PlayerDto { Rounds = playerRounds.Select(playerRound => new RoundDto {}) };
```

Which of these two pieces is more efficient?

Comment: do you mean efficient? if it works at all, its effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing, you really can't know. As a rule of thumb, anything done in LINQ is slower than the same thing done manually; the extra iterators and delegate invocations do have their costs.

However, for most practical purposes I would consider them equal in performance. If the performance really makes a difference (i.e. you are in a very critical block, or you notice a slowdown), you will definitely want to measure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really care about this microptimisation? Your code will be marginally faster, but only noticeable when youre dealing with massive numbers.

Crack out reflector and look how groupJoin works

Comment: Yes, massive numbers and high frequency of messages is something I deal with. It would be great to know how GroupJoin works. If it uses a nested loop than it is definitely less efficient than the first snippet.